# I am trying to make an anchor tag removal function

Tags: javascript

I tried VBA macro from MS Word(the PC i'm currently using doesn't have much stuff), it did not turn out to be great, so I tried it with Firefox console.

This is my current code:

```
function stripAnchorTags(html) {
    return html.replace(/\<a.*\>.*\<\/a\>/, '');
}
console.log(stripAnchorTags('<a href="image location" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img src="image location" border="0" height="400" width="640"></a></div><br><a href="image location" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img src="image location" border="0" height="400" width="640"></a></div>'));
```

Now, the output I want was

`<img src="image location" border="0" height="400" width="640"></div><br><img src="image location" border="0" height="400" width="640"></div>`

But instead of it, I only get `</div>`

I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Don't parse HTLM with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If you give us some insight as to what you are trying to do, maybe we can help you with a better way of doing it. This should be pretty simple to do with jQuery, but are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

1. you need to use "g" to replace all instances.
2. what you were doing was deleting everything between the  tag.

   function stripAnchorTags(html) {
       html = html.replace(/\</a>/g, '');
       html = html.replace(/\]*>/g, '');
       return html;
   }

**===== EDIT =====**

oneliner:

```
function stripAnchorTags(html) {
    return html.replace(/\<a.*?\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/g, '\$1');
}
```